# is it possible to set custom attribute by jQuery attr() function using JS variables

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes

I'm using jquery 1.5 and html4 standard.
 I'm trying to set custom attribute which i get by javascript variable, but it is not setting up.code sample:

```
var attname="list1"; // this is changed on every call of the function where it is defined.    
var attvalue="b,c,d"; // this also changed.  
jQuery('#div1').attr({attname:attvalue});
```

but it treat attname as string itself rather variable.
there are other option like using data(),prop() but they are supported in HTML5 and jquery 1.6 that is not possible for me at the moment.other problem is data can't be set on server side to be sync and used at client side by jquery data(). as they are syntactically diff. 
if there's some other way please suggest
Thanks.

Comment: **karim79** Thanks for edit  @Sedat thanks to point the syntax error i was making. **Brogrammer** ,**Usman**, **Andy** Thanks all for providing input every one was correct in one or other way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess you should use this

```
jQuery('#div').attr(attname,attvalue);
```

Answer (score 16):

Yes, but use `data-` prefix before to avoid collision

```
$('elm').attr('data-'+attname,attvalue);
```

Using `data-` prefix doesn't require HTML5.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can add any attribute you want, just be careful:

```
$('#foobar').attr('foo','bar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/each/rnnfk/ - Check out this demo

Answer (score 3):

```
<div data-test="lala">asdf</div>

alert($('div').data('test'));
var t = 'data-test2';
var v = 'hiho';
$('div').attr(t,v);
alert($('div').data('test2'));
alert($('div').attr('data-test2'));
```

this all works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/r7uQ8/
Tested on jquery 1.4.4

Comment: Pretty sure if you read his question he doesn't want the use of data attributes.

Comment: @Brogrammer: Hm I understood it that way, that he meant he can't use data because he thought they only work in jquery 1.6. So i pointed out that they do work in 1.4.4 as well. And using them would be more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Square bracket notation is your friend:

```
var attname = "haha";
jQuery('#div')[0][attname] = "foo";
alert(jQuery('#div')[0][attname]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJBHq/