# How to change the value of a custom attribute

Tags: jquery

```
var selector = $(this);
```

What is the proper code to change the custom attribute `data-change-me` for `selector`?

The syntax

```
selector[data-change-me='someValue'];
```

Is not working for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to set custom attribute by jQuery attr() function using JS variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497066/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-attribute-by-jquery-attr-function-using-js-variab)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you want the attr method.

```
selector.attr("data-change-me","someValue");
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

It's worth pointing out also that it looked like what you were trying to do was treat the jQuery wrapped DOM object as a Javascript object e.g:

Look at the following example for what I mean:

```
var myObject = {
     "data-change-me":"someValue";
};

myObject["data-change-me"] = "someOtherValue";
```

This is valid syntax for pure Javascript objects but not jQuery. To learn about Javascript I recommend [Javascript the good parts](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0596517742/)

Answer (score 19):

While [Rob Stevenson-Leggett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166486/82548) is perfectly correct, it's important to remember that you can use plain JavaScript for this too:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('div');
selector.setAttribute('data-change-me','red');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pztKh/).

References:

- [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).