# How can I add a value to an attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the value of a custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166478/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-custom-attribute)

I have input field as such:

```
<input type="text" size="40" locationcode="" userid="" id="inputQuery">
```

How can I select the element using its `id` and and put value onto `userid` attribute?

Comment: $('#inputQuery').attr('userid', myval); i can't test on fiddle (timeout problem)

Comment: You should try using the documentation for something as simple as this.

Comment: Also you won't pass validation with those attributes. Try looking into "data-" attributes.

Comment: you can just go to jquery site and look to documentation, and second thing just give yourself a try before get an answer better to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `data-` prefix to add a custom attribute, i.e.

`data-userid="yourValue"`

So in your case you should setup your input like this.

```
<input type="text" size="40" data-locationcode="" data-userid="" id="inputQuery" />
```

Then you can use:

```
$('#inputQuery').attr('data-userid', 'my_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

- Set the value:

`$('#inputQuery').val('VALUE');`

- Get the value:

`$('#inputQuery').val();`

Comment: this isn't what he is asking?